# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_16 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (30,)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm having this error, and from all I've seen from answers to similar questions it is due to not specifying the last layer to have 30 neurons, since your desired output is an array with size 30. But this is not my case, I've specified this, so I find it very weird that this error pops up if the number of neurons and output shape match perfectly. Below there's the part of the code that may be causing this  error (`images_gray` is a numpy array consisting of greyscale images with shape (2000, 128, 128) and `result_array` is a list of numpy arrays of size 30).

```
images_gray = np.reshape(images_gray, (len(images_gray), img_rows, img_cols, 1))
to_shuffle = list(zip(images_gray, result_array))
random.shuffle(to_shuffle)
im_input, res_output = zip(*to_shuffle)
im_input, res_output = np.array(im_input[:10]), np.array(res_output[:10])
img_rows, img_cols, _ = np.shape(im_input[0])
input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (1, img_rows, img_cols)
model = buildCNN(input_shape)
adadelta = keras.optimizers.Adadelta(lr=0.5)
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",optimizer=adadelta,metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(im_input, res_output, batch_size=128, epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

Here's the `buildCNN()` function:

```
def buildCNN(input_shape):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(30, activation='sigmoid'))
    return model
```

And what I get when I use `model.sumary()`:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your target (y values) have length of 30 then I assume that you want to do multiclass classification. In that case, your are using wrong activation function in your output layer which should be `softmax` instead of `sigmoid`.

```
model.add(Dense(30, activation='softmax'))
```

`sigmoid` is used with binary classification.

And if you want to do binary classification, then your target (y values) should have a length of 1, instead of 30.

Also note that you will most likely receive another error because if your target values are one-hot encoded (assuming from the fact that they are arrays of the length of 30) then the correct loss function to pick is `categorical_crossentropy`.

`sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss is used for multiclass classification when labels are provided as integers (not one-hot encoded).

So in the case of one-hot encoded labels, the `compile` method should be called like this

```
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",optimizer=adadelta,metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: I tried this change but I still get the same error, and I tried the relu activation function but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Neither relu nor sigmod can work, that is not how the math/keras works. In case you have one-hot encoded labels, you need softmax with the categorical cross-entropy loss. If this combination gives you an error then you have incorrectly encoded labels.

Comment: Again, make sure that you are using `categorical_crossentropy` loss, not `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss in case of one-hot encoded labels because otherwise, you will face the above-mentioned error.

Comment: I didn't see the comment about the loss, once I changed that too it worked fine. Thanks!